# pandas error when using .append in a loop on data frame with duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, dataframe

I am getting the following errors when trying to append a row from one data frame to my master data frame.

```
newDf = trainFrame.append(bDriftFeed, ignore_index=True)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6673, in append
    other = other.reindex(combined_columns, copy=False)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3734, in reindex
    return super(Series, self).reindex(index=index, **kwargs)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4356, in reindex
    fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4374, in _reindex_axes
    copy=copy, allow_dups=False)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4490, in _reindex_with_indexers
    copy=copy)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1224, in reindex_indexer
    self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3086, in _can_reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
```

My master data frame was setup with these columns

```
columns = ['CartAge1', 'Hct', 'zscore', 'cpk', 'moving2', 'moving5', 'Na', 'zscore', 'cpk', 'moving2', 'moving5', 'K', 'zscore', 'cpk', 'moving2', 'moving5', 'Ca', 'zscore', 'cpk', 'moving2', 'moving5', 'Cl', 'zscore', 'cpk', 'moving2', 'moving5', 'pO2', 'zscore', 'cpk', 'moving2', 'moving5', 'pH', 'zscore', 'cpk', 'moving2', 'moving5', 'Glu', 'zscore', 'cpk', 'moving2', 'moving5', 'pCO2', 'zscore', 'cpk', 'moving2', 'moving5', 'Target']

trainFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

I am trying to iterate over the csv files in a directory, process data into a data frame with a single row, and then append that row to my master data frame. the error only occurs after processing 11 or so files.

From what I have read, this error commonly occurs when using duplicate column names. The column names need to have duplicate values for my application.

Are there any known workarounds for my issue?

Comment: `The column names need to have duplicate values for my application` -- out of curiosity, what application is that? In my (limited) experience, duplicate column names are generally a bad idea.

Comment: I agree its bad practice, but the output needs to be compatible with a third party application using them as the inputs for some reason. Although now that I think about it... I could probably use unique column names for the data frame while looping through all the files and then just overwrite the values when ready for export..